# python automation: time not increasing

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm building an automatic zoom launcher project with selenium and pyautogui and text file to save the data and i use loops to check if it's true or false. The text file looks like this.

Thursday,Test,12:24,Yes,Link,zoom_link
Thursday,Test2,8:30,Yes,Link,zoom_link
I convert the content of the text file into a list and put it in the data list so it looks something like this

```
data = [['Thursday','Test','12:24','Yes','Link','zoom_link'], ['Thursday','Test2','8:30','Yes','Link','zoom_link']]
```

This is the code related to the problem

```
for record in data:
    convert_time_record = datetime.datetime.strptime(record[2], '%H:%M').time()
    date_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    # Datetime and auto validation for web automation 
    while True:
        if record[3] == "Yes":
            if record[4] == "Link":
                if record[0] == date_now.strftime('%A') and convert_time_record == date_now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
                    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
                    driver.get(record[5])
                    try:
                        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
                            ec.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "_3Gj8x8oc"))
                        )
                        element.click()
                        time.sleep(2)
                        open_meeting_btn = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('open_zoom_web.png')
                        pyautogui.moveTo(open_meeting_btn)
                        pyautogui.click()
                    finally:
                        driver.close()
                    print('link action')
                    break
    # Check if the method was by meeting ID
        elif record[4] == "Meeting ID":
            if record[0] == date_now.strftime('%A') and convert_time_record == date_now.strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
                # Open Zoom 
                subprocess.call(zoom_path)
                time.sleep(3)
                # Locate the center of the join button then move the cursor
                join_button = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('join_button.png')
                # Move the cursor to the location
                pyautogui.moveTo(join_button)
                # Click the button
                pyautogui.click()
                time.sleep(3)
                # Write the meeting id to the text field
                pyautogui.write(record[5])
                # Press the enter key
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                time.sleep(3)
                # Write the passcode to the text field
                pyautogui.write(record[6])
                # Press the enter key
                pyautogui.press('enter')
                print('id action')
                break
```

After testing with the Python IDLE, i found why the conditions were never met

```
import datetime
>>> x=datetime.datetime.now()
>>> data = [['Thursday', 'Test', '14:34', 'Yes', 'Link', link]]
>>> for record in data:
    convert = datetime.datetime.strptime(record[2],'%H:%M').time()
    while True:
        if record[0]==x.strftime('%A') and convert==x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'):
            print('true')
            break
        else:
            print('false', convert, x.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

and this is the print result

```
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
false 14:34:00 14:32:00
# ...
```

the `x=datetime.datetime.now()` time is not increasing, how can i fix this?

Comment: `x=datetime.datetime.now()` assigns a value to `x` - if you want to "update" the value of x, you'll have to re-assign the current date/time. Also, note that `convert` is a datetime.time object, which will never compare equal to a string you obtain from x.strftime. In general, it's not a good idea to check for exact equality when dealing with time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x`  in `x=datetime.datetime.now()` gets set every time you call this function. In your example you seem to only set x to be the currtent time once. If you do not call the function `datetime.datetime.now()` again, and set `x` to be the current time, x will stay the same.

You need to run this line `x=datetime.datetime.now()` every time you want the current time. In this example we call `datetime.datetime.now()` 5 times in the for loop.

```
import datetime
import time

for i in range(5):
    x=datetime.datetime.now()
    print("x = ", x)
    time.sleep(1)

Out [2]:

x =  2020-10-15 10:27:26.001649
x =  2020-10-15 10:27:27.009904
x =  2020-10-15 10:27:28.015560
x =  2020-10-15 10:27:29.024214
x =  2020-10-15 10:27:30.031730
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `x=datetime.datetime.now()` you are calling the function and x is a reference to the result. So x will always be the same date when you later use it. As a consequence `x.strftime('%A')` will always give you the same result.
What you want is to have a reference to the funciton to call it everytime you need it. In python you can use assign funcitons to variables just like values.
So you can do `x=datetime.datetime.now` (No brackets at the end here) and then call x with `current_time=x()` or `current_time_string= x().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`.

Comment: instead of assigning the `now()` method to some variable, don't you think it is more readable to just call `datetime.datetime.now()` whenever needed? also, `x` strictly is not a reference.

Comment: In what way is ‘x’ not a reference?

Comment: @MrFuppes yes maybe its more readable but in this case i think its more important to understand the concept of what is happening. Yea will edit the reference thing

Comment: don't worry about the term *reference*; it just might be misleading in some context. here, `x` is an instance of class datetime.datetime, with attributes set to represent current date and time.

Comment: @quamrana if i remember right under the hood in pyython everything is a reference but because datetime is immutable it will act like a pass by value.

Comment: Immutability has very little to do with it. now() returns an instance of class datetime. Variables can only ever refer to it. While it’s true there are no mutating methods it’s still passed around as a reference.

Comment: @quamrana: passed around as an *object* reference.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was implied by *instance of class*.